# Object is invisible/transparent to the renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have an object that is for some reason transparent to the renderer. I have tried flipping normals, recalculating them, everything I could think of to make it work, but in the end it doesn't show up in Blender Render, and it only shows up in Cycles, but them Freestyle shows through it.

Blend File: [Google Drive to my blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F80B4jJW_hFjugYN5XYDPs_184XrJ3sL/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Freestyle showing through the neck of an object.]